# How to represent an image from database in JSON

Tags: java, json, url, jdbc, blob

I need to create JSON based on a blob from database. To get the blob image, I use the code below and after show in json array:

```
Statement s = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet r = s.executeQuery("select image from images");
while (r.next()) {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("img", r.getBlob("image"));
}
```

I to want return a JSON object for the each image according the image blob. How can I achieve it?

Comment: What's the ultimate goal? Showing it as `<img>` in a HTML page? Can't you just return an URL with some image identifier as request parameter and return the image as response when the URL has actually been requested?

Comment: BalusC, I need generate URL to each r.getBlob("image") and I dont know to do. This will be used by mobile application through json.

Comment: Ah, you want to transfer images to mobile devices via JSON? Encode it as Base64 then?

Comment: I understand. Well, I have the images of blob types in my database. I to want distribute the images in my API Json, but I dont know to do.

Comment: Exactly. I wanna to transfer images to mobile devices via json.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Binary data in JSON is usually best to be represented in a [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)-encoded form. You could use the standard Java SE provided [`DatatypeConverter#printBase64Binary()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html) method to Base64-encode a byte array.

```
byte[] imageBytes = resultSet.getBytes("image");
String imageBase64 = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(imageBytes);
obj.put("img", imageBase64);
```

The other side has just to Base64-decode it. E.g. in Android, you could use the builtin [`android.util.Base64`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html) API for this.

```
byte[] imageBytes = Base64.decode(imageBase64, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: Working with small data the code is excellent but working with big data, always happening out of memory. Any idea to optimize the code to avoid out of memory? In general, 2000 items to converter images.

Comment: Indeed, each byte of a `byte[]` allocates one byte of JVM memory. So in case of 2000 images each 100KB, already 200MB is eaten away, then I'm not talking about Base64 encoding overhead. Use `Base64OutputStream` from commons codec instead which you feed with the `InputStream` from `ResultSet#getBinaryStream()` (and don't use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` as output source as it uses under the covers a `byte[]` as well!).

Comment: I'm not sure how to interpret that. Just wanted to confirm that you've seen a "don't" in the last sentence.

Comment: OPSSSS! Now on. Indeed, I will to search about Base64OutputStream. ;-P

Comment: I attached the lib from commons codec but still I dont understand how to use Base64OutputStream. Do you have any sample?

Comment: @SchlacterJames Use jackson streaming API

Comment: @BalusC The same problem. Cannot use the base64 to generate json because the file is huge. No Way. How can I generate a url for each image from database? Any idea?

Comment: @BalusC Your answer helps me a lot, I put the link of this post into my question's answer, thank you. Here is my question's link:
[Get BLOB from database how to put them back](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21268723/get-blob-from-database-how-to-put-them-back)