# Get BLOB from database, how to put them back

Tags: database, oracle, jdbc, blob

I got the BLOB data from the database and use the below code to put it into a string(rs is the ResultSet, file is a Map), is there a way to put this string value back to the BLOB columns?

```
                    Blob blob = rs.getBlob("FILE_DATA");
                    if(blob != null) {
                        byte[] bdata = blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length());
                        String data = new String(bdata);
                        file.put("FILE_DATA", data);
                    }
```

I have tried some suggestions like this one, but they don't work well.

```
            Blob blbVal = getConnection().createBlob();
            byte[] fileData = value.toString().getBytes();
            blbVal.setBytes(1, fileData);
            cs.setBlob(index, blbVal);
```

Comment: Please qualify what "but they don't work well." actually means.  Doesn't work at all?  Do you get a specific Oracle error?  Or does it work, but there's some related problem?  Performance?

Comment: Why are you storing text data in a BLOB instead of a CLOB?

Comment: @MarkJ.Bobak Sorry about this, it does not work at all, there is a exception like this `java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.createBlob()Ljava/sql/Blob;`

Comment: @GriffeyDog I don't think this is text data, I am doing a copy function, the data will be fetched from the database and send back to the client by restful web service, then the client need to insert the data into their database. There are a lot of data, for this BLOB, I don't know what is inside, I just need to put it back as what it is before. Thank you.

Comment: You're putting the BLOB into a `String`, so you have character/text/string data whether you want it or not.

Comment: @GriffeyDog yeah, but the database on the client has totally the same tables, so the data was in BLOB, I have to put it back into the BLOB columns.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the way I put the BLOB into the String is also not correct, if we don't encode the BLOB data, it will be lost.

Here I found another post which solved this issue perfectly. Thanks for BalusC's answer
[How to represent an image from database in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897297/how-to-represent-an-image-from-database-in-json)